# Python a harder itertools.product problem with defined grouping

Tags: python, recursion, python-itertools, backtracking, cartesian-product

So here is the issue.

First, here is normal itertools.product operation:

```
x = [[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]
itertools.product(*x)
```

The output is:

`>>> [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]`

Now `x` is an array of length 3. Let's say I define a "group plan":

```
# Note 0th and 1st group indices are both 0, indicating they are of the same group.
group plan = [0, 0, 1]
```

My goal is to implement a

`def my_itertools_product_with_group(*args, group_plan=[0, 0, 1])`
The correct solutions will be:

```
>>> [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Because we can see for the 0th and 1st element of each list,  they are the same, either `[0, 0]` or `[1, 1]`

Another example:
`arr = [['a0', 'A0'], ['a1', 'A1'], ['a2', 'A2'], ['a3', 'A3'], ['a4', 'A4'], ['a5', 'A5']]`

The grouping scheme defined as `[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2]`
In that sense, still want to find all possible combinations

```
result = my_itertools_product_with_group(*arr, group_plan=[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2])
```

The legal outputs are:

```
result = [\
['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5']
['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'A5']
['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'A3', 'a4', 'a5']
['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'A3', 'a4', 'A5']

['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'a3', 'A4', 'a5']
['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'a3', 'A4', 'A5']
['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'a5']
['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5']]
```

**My attempts:**
I can do post filtering after calling normal `itertool.product()`, but am also wondering if it is possible to do it in one-shot as defined by the `def my_itertools_product_with_group(*args, group_plan)`

Here is my post-filtering code where you can see, I first get cartesian product of `[ [0, 1] * 5 ]`.

```
group_plan = [0, 0, 1, 2, 0] # meaning all elements marked as 0 should be treated as the same group

result = [x for x in itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=5) if grouped_as_planned(x, group_plan)]

...
    def grouped_as_planned(arr, group_plan):
        for x_ind, x in enumerate(arr):
            for y_ind in range(x_ind + 1, len(arr)):
                if group_plan[x_ind] == group_plan[y_ind]:
                    if x != arr[y_ind]:
                        return False
        return True
```

Comment: Please share what you have attempted to implement the said behavior, and ask specific questions about the problems you're having with your implementation.

Comment: I don't know how to start the implementation

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: Your problem specification is hard to understand, in part because your first example is a *negative* one that doesn't clearly explain the rationale.

Comment: [I’m stuck](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/), without specifics of *how* you're stuck, is an issue for a tutor in problem analysis or specification.  It’s not focused enough for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Prune Apologies. I have updated the description.

Comment: very interesting question :) . I have added a solution, do check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting question. Here is a solution.

I use `defaultdict` for grouping, `numpy.argsort` for storing original order of arrays and `itertools.product` for taking products.

Explanation inline as comments:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict
import itertools

def my_itertools_product_with_group(arr, group_plan):
    order = np.argsort(group_plan) #Stores the original order for the columns
    
    #Grouper dictionary for group plan
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for i,j in zip(group_plan, arr):
        d[i].append(j)
    
    stack = [zip(*v) for k,v in d.items()] #Inter-group stacker for each group
    prod = itertools.product(*stack)       #itertools product
    flat = [[k for j in i for k in j ] for i in prod] #Flatten ragged tensor from 3D to 2D
    reorder = np.array(flat)[:,order].tolist() #Reorder based on original order and return
    return reorder
```

Testing it out on your complex case:

```
arr = [['a0', 'A0'], ['a1', 'A1'], ['a2', 'A2'], ['a3', 'A3'], ['a4', 'A4'], ['a5', 'A5']]
group_plan = [0,0,0,1,0,2]

my_itertools_product_with_group(arr, group_plan)
```

```
[['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'A5'],
 ['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'A3', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'A3', 'a4', 'A5'],
 ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'a3', 'A4', 'a5'],
 ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'a3', 'A4', 'A5'],
 ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'a5'],
 ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5']]
```

Another example:

```
arr = [[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]
group_plan = [0,0,1]

my_itertools_product_with_group(arr, group_plan)
```

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

---

## Explanation:

Let's break it down step by step.

1. Store original order for reordering in the last step:

```
order = np.argsort(group_plan)
order

# array([0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5])
```

2. Use `defaultdict` to group items belonging to same group:

```
d = defaultdict(list)
for i,j in zip(group_plan, arr):
    d[i].append(j)
    
dict(d)

#{0: [['a0', 'A0'], ['a1', 'A1'], ['a2', 'A2'], ['a4', 'A4']],
# 1: [['a3', 'A3']],
# 2: [['a5', 'A5']]}
```

3. Stack the list of lists for each of the groups (transpose)

```
stack = [list(zip(*v)) for k,v in d.items()]
stack

#[[('a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a4'), ('A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A4')],
# [('a3',), ('A3',)],
# [('a5',), ('A5',)]]
```

4. Take `itertools.product` between the stacked/grouped items

```
prod = list(itertools.product(*stack))
prod

#[(('a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a4'), ('a3',), ('a5',)),
# (('a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a4'), ('a3',), ('A5',)),
# (('a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a4'), ('A3',), ('a5',)),
# (('a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a4'), ('A3',), ('A5',)),
# (('A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A4'), ('a3',), ('a5',)),
# (('A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A4'), ('a3',), ('A5',)),
# (('A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A4'), ('A3',), ('a5',)),
# (('A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A4'), ('A3',), ('A5',))]
```

5. Flatten the innermost tuple to get a list of lists in the ragged matrix.

```
flat = [[k for j in i for k in j ] for i in prod]
flat

#[['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a4', 'a3', 'a5'],
# ['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a4', 'a3', 'A5'],
# ['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a4', 'A3', 'a5'],
# ['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a4', 'A3', 'A5'],
# ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A4', 'a3', 'a5'],
# ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A4', 'a3', 'A5'],
# ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A4', 'A3', 'a5'],
# ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A4', 'A3', 'A5']]
```

6. Reorder numpy array using the original order stored and convert back to list

```
reorder = np.array(flat)[:,order].tolist()
reorder

#[['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'],
# ['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'A5'],
# ['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'A3', 'a4', 'a5'],
# ['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'A3', 'a4', 'A5'],
# ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'a3', 'A4', 'a5'],
# ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'a3', 'A4', 'A5'],
# ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'a5'],
# ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this directly, but it's not quite as easy: you have to drive the logic from the viewpoint of your grouping scheme, as that defines what you have for independent elements.

I suggest that you set up a table, keyed by the grouping index.  The values will be the list choices and their placement in the solution.  Let's take a shorter version of your second example, with only four elements (instead of six).

```
arr = [['a0', 'A0'], ['a1', 'A1'], ['a2', 'A2'], ['a3', 'A3']]
grouping_plan = [0, 1, 0, 2]
```

This shows that you have to link groups 0 & 2.  Your table will look like this:

```
group   pos      values
  0    [0, 2]    [['a0', a2'], ['A0, A2]]
  1     [1]      [['a1'], ['A1']]
  3     [3]      [['a3'], ['A3']]
```

Now, you call `product` on you list of values.  You will get items such as

```
[['a0', a2'], ['A1'], ['a3']]
```

Now, you refer to your in-order grouping indices:

```
[[0, 2], [1], [3]]
```

Flatten both lists, zip them, `sort` on the index, and you have the desired order.

Coding details are left as an exercise for the reader.  :-)